# how to validate form with js and store errors

Tags: javascript, php, html

js validation standard w3sc

I modify it to store error messages in div, but it wont work after first err cause it's returns false.
how do i add with inner html in div several error messages? something like:

```
  <div id"err">Name is empty,Price is empty,SKU is empty,</div>
```

other code down here, obviously if I take out return:false; then input will reload page, that's what I want to avoid

```js
function validateForm() {

  if (document.forms["form)"]["sku"].value == "") {
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML += "SKU is empty,";
    return false;
  }
  if (document.forms["form)"]["name"].value == "") {
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML += "Name is empty,";
    return false;
  }
  if (document.forms["form)"]["price"].value == "") {
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML += "Price is empty,";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form)" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  sku: <input type="text" name="sku">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  price: <input type="text" name="price">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="err"></div>
```

Comment: You might want to review your code snippet as the HTML code and the JavaScript code do not match (different name of the form, different name of the inputs, different number of input). Anyway, in general, you should remove the `return false` from each if clause and put a single return at the end of the function, if the array where you are storing errors is not empty.

Comment: hey man thanks i did edited names

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this version using addEventListener and preventDefault

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  const errDiv = document.getElementById("err");
  errDiv.innerHTML = ""
  const err = []
  if (this.name.value.trim() == "") err.push("Name is empty");
  if (this.sku.value.trim() == "")  err.push("SKU is empty");
  if (+this.price.value == 0)       err.push("Price is empty");

  if (err.length) {
    errDiv.innerHTML = err.join("<br/>");
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
  SKU: <input type="text" name="sku"> Price: <input type="number" name="price">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="err"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `validateForm` function should look something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  let errorString = "";
  let form = document.forms["form)"];

  if (form["sku"] === "") 
    errorString += "Sku is empty, ";

  if (form["name"] === "")
    errorString += "name is empty, ";

  if (form["price"] === "")
    errorString += "price is empty, ";

  document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = errorString;

  return errorString === "";
}
```

Comment: I think my array is more elegant. You now have one long string with unnecessary trailing commas

Comment: You're right (but it answers the question the user asked). I also think that there were some parts of your answer that might be quite confusing for a beginner, but maybe you learn faster by being confronted with new things